# Python 3.6 interpreter refuses to input spaces unless I'm holding option

Tags: python, interpreter, macos-high-sierra

Instead of inputting the space, terminal acts as if I hit an invalid character (blinks and makes a sound effect). However, if I hold option while pressing space it works like normal (which turns out to be a non-breaking space). Everything is fine outside the interpreter, but within it only spaces refuse to input.

This occurs with Python 3.6.3 on macOS High Sierra. I can't pinpoint when exactly it started happening because I hadn't touched Python in a long time, but after updating to High Sierra and coming back to Python I noticed this problem. I have tried removing all PIP packages, reinstalling Python 2 and 3 to no avail.

Here is video:
https://streamable.com/psy7p

Comment: Try restarting? If that doesn't work, I think you must have strange terminal settings or something because this is really weird behaviour...

Comment: Re-installing Python? What Python are you using? It is installed by default in /usr/bin/ ; have you used that one?

Comment: @Evert I'm using Python 3.6 installed via Homebrew, not the default version of Python on macOS. The default version (as well as Python 2 through Homebrew) both have no issues. Just Python 3.

Comment: You may have wandered into a proper Python bug then, if other versions work fine. Perhaps find a suitable Python mailing list and ask there (or even file it as a bug). Though some people on the mailing lists/bug tracker list may browse StackOverflow as well. Of course, it may also be a Homebrew packaging bug(!)

Comment: To try: see if Homebrew left Python 3.6.2 around. Usually somewhere in `<prefix>/Cellar/.../<version>/.../bin/python3.6`. You can attempt a `find <prefix> -name python3.6` to see if you find older versions. Then see if any of the older 3.6 versions behave normally.

Comment: Fwiw: I can't reproduce this (High Sierra, Terminal, bash, Python 3.6.3).

Comment: @Evert Unfortunately, Homebrew doesn't have any previous versions of 3.6 saved and I can't find anything on the bug tracker list for this issue. I might just end up reinstalling macOS if I don't find anything further. It's strange because I haven't configured terminal nor Homebrew nor Python in any special way, yet this issue seems so specific to my machine.

Comment: I can only offer suggestions, one of them trying to see if the same happens if you use iTerm instead. You could try to use a different shell (e.g., if you use bash, try (t)csh or zsh). These things may not be your preference, but they could help in trimming down the options and finding the actual cause.

Comment: You could even try and go as far as writing a script that uses [`code.InteractiveConsole`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html#code.InteractiveConsole), and run that with 3.6.3, to see if that shows the same problem. Depending on your debugging tastes and efforts.

Comment: @Evert I did try with iTerm and also with zsh separately but still the issue persisted. I discovered however that installing and using Python 3.6.3 from the official website fixed the problem. Pointing back to Homebrew Python gave me the problem again. It's all a bit over my head, but at least it's a temporary solution without having to reinstall everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I stumbled upon an answer finally after attempting to setup a postgres server and having the same issue in the interactive command mode.

A long time ago I created an .inputrc file to use the Magic Space feature which overrides the space key to a magic-space, which only bash recognizes but otherwise mainly functions the same as a normal space. I had completely forgotten about this. I ended up wrapping this in a conditional, which fixes the space issue finally. I still wonder why Python 2.xx versions worked fine though.

This answer was helpful:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315137/i-cannot-type-space-in-interactive-command-mode